# cumulative distribution of intersection of events

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ be independent identically distributed random variables having common distribution function $F_X(\cdot)$. Express the event 'the smallest of the $X$s exceeds $k$' as an intersection of $n$ events, each involving one of the $X$s. Deduce that the distribution function of the smallest value is $G(k) = 1-(1-F_X(k))^n$.

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBoCL.png)

I put $Y = \bigcap_i^n X_i$ and I think the question is asking me to show that $P(Y > k)$ However:

$$P(Y > k ) = \prod_i^n P(X_i > k) = (1- F_X(k))^n$$

So I am unsure what the question is asking, or if I am going wrong.

Comment: Consider typing your question(s) instead of posting an image so that others will be able to search for it. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M = \min\{X_1,\dotsc,X_n\}$.
Then
notice that
$$\{M>k\}\iff \{X_1>k,\dotsc,X_n>k\}\iff \left\{\bigcap_{i=1}^n(X_i>k)\right\}$$
and
\begin{align*}
P(M>k) &=P\left\{\bigcap_{i=1}^n(X_i>k)\right\}\\
&=P(X_1>k,\dotsc,X_n>k)\\
&=P(X_1>k)\dotsm P(X_n>k)\\
&=[1-P(X_1<k)]\dotsm[1-P(X_n<k)]\\
&=[1-F_X(k)]^n.
\end{align*}

Finally notice that
$$F_M(k) = P(M\leq k) = 1-P(M>k) = 1-[1-F_X(k)]^n. $$

Comment: Is my intersection incorrect? As the question asks for it

Comment: I mean that you used "\min{X_1,...,X_n}" and i used $\bigcap_i X_i

Comment: @FACEIT I believe the correct intersection is $\bigcap_{i=1}^n(X_i>k)$.

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense, thanks.

Comment: @FACEIT No problem, glad to help when people post all their thoughts and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You were correct, *except* that you were asked to find the CDF of the minimum order statistic, $X_{(1)}=\min\{X_i\}$, which is actually the probability of the complement of that intersection (of all $X_i>k$).

$$\begin{align}G(k) & = F_{X_{(1)}}(k) \\[1ex] & = \mathsf P(\bigcup_{i}\{X_i\leq k\}) \\[2ex] & = 1- \mathsf P(\bigcap_i \{X_i > k\}) \\[2ex] & = 1-\prod_i \mathsf P(X_i>k) \\[2ex] & = 1-\big(1-F_X(k)\big)^n\end{align}$$

That is all.